# Scalar when undefined: real, complex, or something else

Tags: convention

For an arbitrary vector space one defines, the scalar field can be anything: real, complex, rational, or some other previously defined field.

However, in some texts on linear algebra for example, the authors do not define what a *scalar* is. Is it conventional to assume that, unless specified otherwise, a *scalar* is a real number? If not, in what topics, if any, is the conventional *scalar* taken to be complex numbers or some other field?

I realize this question may be somewhat fluffy, but I'd appreciate any inputs you may have.

Comment: In order to be perfectly unambiguous, one would (*and should*) say things like "Let $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ be the vector space **over the reals** of all continuous functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$" in order to emphasize what the scalar field is.

Answer (score 1):

A scalar is simply an element of the field where the vector space is defined over.

It is usually understood what field you are working over.

So if V is a k-vector space, then a scalar is an element of k.